# Trying to connect boto3 to linode object storage

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I cannot seem to connect to Linode Object Storage with boto3. It seems like this is something that is supported, but I cannot find the right syntax. I have tried adding http/https to endpoint_url and adding bucket name, but nothing is allowing url to be accepted.

Here is my code

```
import boto3

linode_obj_config = {
    "aws_access_key_id": "1S**J",
    "aws_secret_access_key": "YJ**25gjqS3",
    "endpoint_url": "us-southeast-1.linodeobjects.com",
}

client = boto3.client("s3", **linode_obj_config)
response = client.list_objects(Bucket='order-book-snapshots')
for object in response['Contents']:
    print(object['Key'])
```

Here is the error:

```
  File "/home/bb/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 402, in create_endpoint
    raise ValueError("Invalid endpoint: %s" % endpoint_url)
ValueError: Invalid endpoint: us-southeast-1.linodeobjects.com
```

Comment: Looks like its expecting a url, try adding `https://`.

Answer (score 1):

After trying every variation of the url, I also added `use_ssl: True` to the client and `https://` to the url, and now it is listing the keys.